# SQL Server CLR - SqlDataRecord.SetValue InvalidCastException

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, casting, sqlclr

I'm working on setting up a large set of stored procedures using SQL CLR. I'm currently in debugging mode.

I'm trying to write a data set back to the client using `SqlPipe`.

Here's my code:

```
Dim metaData() As SqlMetaData = {New SqlMetaData("USERNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1), _
                                 New SqlMetaData("CASEID", SqlDbType.BigInt), _
                                 New SqlMetaData("Reason", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1)}
Dim record As New SqlDataRecord(metaData)
Dim pipe As SqlPipe = SqlContext.Pipe
pipe.SendResultsStart(record)
Dim username = iDataRow.Item("USERNAME")
Dim caseId = Convert.ToInt32(identifier.CASEID)
Dim message = "Message"
record.SetValue(0, username)
record.SetValue(1, caseId)
record.SetValue(2, message)
pipe.SendResultsRow(record)
pipe.SendResultsEnd()
```

`identifier.CASEID` is a value stored in the database as a `numeric(21)`, but it's actually a six-digit number, which is why I selected `SqlDbType.BigInt` as the `SqlMetaData` container. In the line where I set the record's "CASEID", (`record.SetValue(1, caseId)`), I keep getting an `InvalidCastException`.

I'm new to this whole SQL CLR thing, but it seems to me that a `System.Int32` ought to be compatible with `SqlDbType.BigInt`. What am I missing?

Comment: msdn info shows that SqlDataRecord.SetValue throws only ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: Good point... re-running now to see if I can get more info from my debug environment... Thanks!

Comment: I get the same error: 
Error Type: `System.InvalidCastException`
Message: `Specified cast is not valid.` 
TargetSite: `{Void SetValue(Int32,System.Object)}`
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: So, it looks like I should have been paying closer attention to my tutorial video (mad props to `www.pluralsight-training.net`!!!), because it's a very simple solution: Instead of `.SetValue...`, I needed to use `.SetInt64...`. Gosh, I feel dumb!

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it throws System.InvalidCastException. Replacing

```
Dim caseId = Convert.ToInt32(identifier.CASEID)
```

with

```
Dim caseId = Convert.ToInt64(identifier.CASEID)
```

has to solve this issue. SqlDataRecord.SetValue method for SqlMetaData with SqlDbType.BigInt expects that input value should be either Int64 or SqlInt64

Comment: Why would it not allow an implicit cast when it's not a narrowing cast? I'll test your solution, and you may be right, but it seems odd to me that it would expect an `Int64` and reject an `Int32`, right? Thanks for replying!